# Insert Data in Dynamic Column of a Table in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to Insert the Data in to a Table which have variable columns.

Comment: Good luck. Another attempt to invent silver buller

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask, to include examples of what you are attempting.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.